# Can Hellfire missiles be used effectively as air-to-air weapons?

Tags: military, missiles

Consider the following hypothetical scenario:

An MQ-1 Predator pilot sees an Su-27 closing in from straight ahead for a kill. <strike>The pilot prepares to write up his 10th loss of the week when he has an idea:</strike> He targets the Su-27 with the laser designator and fires two [AGM-114 Hellfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AGM-114_Hellfire) missiles.

Would this work? Can Hellfire missiles be used effectively as air-to-air weapons?

Comment: No. A Su-27 won't come from straight ahead in the first place. The fighter will use guns, maybe from six o'clock, but don't count on it.

Comment: That's why unmanned fighters are under development.

Comment: Why try to target the enemy fighter with the MQ-1 when [you can just have your F-22 escorts chat with them instead](http://www.military.com/daily-news/2013/09/17/welsh-f22-flew-to-drones-rescue-off-iran-coast.html?ESRC=airforce-a.nl)? `"He flew under their aircraft to check out their weapons load without them knowing that he was there, and then pulled up on their left wing and then called them and said ‘you really ought to go home.' "` Not a good day to be an Iranian F-4 pilot.

Comment: In this situation I'd just turn on my rainbow designator and fire a heat seeking unicorn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I can't say that I know the too much about Hellfires, the aiming capability appears *extremely* limited for any air-to-air combat.

- The range is bad: ~8km (compared to ~35km for a 'proper' Sidewinder). Covering this does not take many seconds for jets travelling in opposite directions. I'd imagine you might be able to get a helicopter if you're lucky.
- I'm incredibly doubtful that a sensible lock on any aircraft could be achieved from a Predator. Bear in mind that you only have a camera on the bottom, so you've got huge blind spots.
- You got a fair bit of satellite/communication lag, in the range of 0.5 seconds either way to get any response. More likely that your opponent has already got you by the time you understand what's going on.
- The majority of the Hellfire missiles appear to require a constant lock to seek its target; some can continue on autopilot with limitations if it were to lose it. Again, sustaining a lock with that setup does not have a good outlook.
- Remember that the Su-27 has countermeasures (such as flares) to protect itself.

Comment: Flares divert Heat seeking missiles, They won't help anything against other guidance methods like laser, radar or Optical.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, hellfire missiles have been used as air-to-air missiles, albeit only once.

On 24 May 2001, an IDAF AH-64 Apache used two hellfire missiles to [shoot down](http://edition.cnn.com/2001/WORLD/meast/05/24/israel.plane.02/index.html?_s=PM:WORLD) a Lebanese Cessna 152. This is the only known use of hellfire missile so far as an air-to-air missile.

However, it is doubtful if the missile could be employed against a extremely maneuverable target like the Su-27. The AGM 114 is basically a anti-tank missile and not suited for use against aerial targets. The Cessna 152 was piloted by a student pilot and in any case had little maneuverability.

Another issue is that the laser designator has to continuously point at the aircraft through out the guidance phase, which is very difficult in the case of a predator against any fighter aircraft.

Also, the range is poor. All in all, unless the pilot is extremely lucky, a predator is not going to get a Su-27. Maybe a helicopter from its blind spot though.